# Unable to @Autowired spring bean in a servlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired, servlet-3.0

I have been trying to autowire a bean inside a servlet but failed to do so. Existing answers in the stackoverflow seems to be not working in my case.

Here is my code :

web.xml

```
<web-app>
   <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

   <context-param>
       <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
       <param-value>
           org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
       </param-value>
   </context-param>

   <context-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>org.springsource.cloudfoundry.mvc.services.config.ServicesConfiguration</param-value>
   </context-param>

   <listener>
       <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>

   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
           <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/beans.xml</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>service</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>com.devesh.learn.mvc.controllers.RestClient</servlet-class>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>service</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

       <welcome-file-list>/hello</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

A simple pojo Webclient which I want to autowire

```
public class WebClient {

    private String id;

    public WebClient() {
        super();
        System.out.println("webclient");
    }

    public void process() {
        System.out.println("Webclient process completed.");
    }

}
```

Servlet RestClient.java

```
public class RestClient extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -752661275356306956L;
    private String id;

    @Autowired
    private WebClient webClient;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private WebApplicationContext springContext;

      @Override
        public void init(final ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
            super.init(config);
            springContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(config.getServletContext());
            final AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory = springContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
            beanFactory.autowireBean(this);
        }


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        super.doGet(req, resp);
        System.out.println("Request reached doGet");        
        webClient.process();
    }

}
```

And the beans.xml file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="webClient" class="com.devesh.situation.WebClient" autowire-candidate="true">
    </bean>

    <bean id="restClient" class="com.devesh.learn.mvc.controllers.RestClient"></bean>

    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>

</beans>
```

The problem is that the field webclient in the Servlet class RestClient is null. I am using spring version 4.2.2.RELEASE dependency (org.springframework:spring-webmvc) for my project.

Here are the error logs

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.devesh.learn.mvc.controllers.RestClient': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.devesh.situation.WebClient com.devesh.learn.mvc.controllers.RestClient.webClient; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.devesh.situation.WebClient] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:302)
    at com.devesh.learn.mvc.controllers.RestClient.init(RestClient.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.devesh.situation.WebClient com.devesh.learn.mvc.controllers.RestClient.webClient; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.devesh.situation.WebClient] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 15 more
```

**Any help will be much appreciated.**

Comment: what is the package structure of the two beans? Is the package structure same as defined in the xml file? Also, is this package visible to the spring container? If not, then this beans will not be created.

Comment: If you've already integrated Spring MVC into the application - why don't you use MVC's controllers managed by spring and therefore not require "manual" autowiring instead of HttpServlet which is managed by Web Container?

Comment: You may need to add `@Component` annotation to your `Webclient` class - it is not clear from your code snippets how you configured this class to be accessible by Spring.

Comment: I have defined WebClient as a bean in xml file.

Comment: The package names are same as given in the xml. In the logs I can also see my constructor of the WebClient being called which means the bean was created, but the question is then why it is not autowired.